# Comparar datas em um array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, datetime

Na variável datas, está recebendo diversas datas em `string` como `array`, quero trazer a menor

```
cont = 0
menor_data = datetime.strptime('31/12/2300', '%d/%m/%Y')
while cont < len(datas):
    data_d = datetime.strptime(datas[cont], '%d/%m/%Y').date()
    if data_d < menor_data:
        menor_data = data_d[cont]
    cont = cont + 1
print(menor_data)
```

Retorna o seguinte erro:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> in
>
> if data_d < menor_data:
>
> TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date

Comment: Nesse caso, a mensagem de erro te diz exatamente o que está acontecendo. Não sei se é produtivo uma resposta completa - o coneslho é que você tente ler a mensagem de erro. Se não souber ingles nem pra isso, use um tradutor automático (mas pode piorar, já que o tradutor não saberá o que é nome de classe e o que é frase)

Comment: na tua variável menor_data tenta colocar o método .date() para retornar o mesmo tipo que você está criando dentro do while. Eles devem ser do mesmo tipo, ou datetime ou date.

Comment: Entendo a mensagem, porem não estava vendo que faltava o .date(), Obrigado!

Comment: @Marlysson sugiro que escreva seu comentário como resposta para que o OP possa aceitar a sua resposta, e assim marcar a pergunta como respondida.

Comment: @dot.Py Blz.

Como sugerido coloquei meu comentário como resposta, se ela ajudou a resolver o problema marque ela como a correta para posteriores consultas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na tua variável `menor_data` tenta colocar o método `.date()` para retornar o mesmo tipo que você está criando dentro do while.

Eles devem ser do mesmo tipo, ou `datetime` ou `date`.